# Getting distance of a point in a 2d triangle without calculating perpendicular vectors?

Tags: java, math, trigonometry

Alright, so I'm trying to get the distance of a point in a 2d triangle without calculating perpendicular vectors.

```
float qd = Vector2f.dot(new Vector2f(pos.x, pos.z),
                        new Vector2f(normal.pos.x, normal.pos.z)) -
           Vector2f.dot(new Vector2f(q.center.x, q.center.z),
                        new Vector2f(normal.pos.x, normal.pos.z));
```

That's the code I'm using. (Note: it's converting 3f vectors to 2d ones, but you don't have to worry about that). I need the result of the calculation to be between 0 and 1 I.E. 0.5 or something.

If I'm still not explaining right maybe this will help?
[image: Axis Example]

My question is: How do I get the distance of a point in a 2d triangle without calculating perpendicular vector's distance? I.E. if the triangle is facing up (y = -1) without any tilt
I would need the distance in the triangle without any X.

Edit1: About what you're saying, Banthar, This is what I got out of it, and it doesn't work, but it seems like it's close to working.

```
float d = (float) Math.sqrt( 0 /*cause the two x's should be the same */ + Math.pow(pos.z - q.max.z, 2));   
float h = (float) Math.sqrt( 0 /*cause the two x's should be the same */ + Math.pow(q.min.z - q.max.z, 2)); 

float myDist = d/h;
```

Comment: "Distance of a point" - distance from where?

Comment: Also, this is really a maths question, not a programming question, so is probably off-topic.

Comment: distance of a point inside a 2d triangle? as in "how far am I from the bottom and top?"

Comment: It looks like you want distance to the base divided by altitude.

Comment: @Banthar, can you explain that a bit more?

Comment: Like [this](http://i.imgur.com/id3y4.png). You don't really care about the triangle. You just want the distance from point `B` to line `k` relative to distance between `A` and `k`. Is that correct?

Comment: yeah, that seems correct, but if the triangle is tilted say 45 degrees I need the equation to follow the line of the triangle, so I need the triangle's normal, so I know which way it's pointing (which I already have) so what I need to know is how to apply this equation to the normal, I think..

Comment: CyanPrime: About your code: Just because you *can* write something as a one liner does not mean you *should* do so.

Comment: @Banthar, see my new edit on the bottom.

Comment: @CyanPrime you need to calculate `d` and `h` using correct [formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line). You can optimize it a little but there is no way around that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say your triangle is ABC and the point is P.
The number you are looking for is the distance from P to AB divided by the distance from C to AB.
This is the same as the ratio of the corresponding areas. So you can compute the two areas:

```
Area(ABP) / Area(ABC)
```

The best way to compute the triangle area depends on what information you have about your triangle.

If you have the vertices only, then you can use:

```
Area(ABP) / Area(ABC) = ( Ax*By - Ax*Py + Ay*Px - Ay*Bx + Bx*Py - By*Px ) /
                        ( Ax*By - Ax*Cy + Ay*Cx - Ay*Bx + Bx*Cy - By*Cx )
```